# Combining AND and OR (e.g. with round brackets) in Mybatis Dynamic SQL

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-dynamic-sql

I need to build a complex query, in part from a "filter framework". A filter framework is a reflective component that adds up as many `and` filters as possible automagically.

I have successfully created the filter framework that generates `and` filters based on user input via MVC. The following is a typical query

```
SELECT * from Entity
WHERE
    attribute1 = ?
AND attribute2 > ?
AND attribute3 IN (????);
```

In Mybatis Dynamic SQL, you chain up calls to `AbstractWhereDSL.and` and you are done.

Given that I have a reference to an automatically-generated `WhereApplier`, which is a `Consumer<AbstractWhereDSL<?>>`, I need to chain up another condition that is a complex condition. The resulting query MUST be

```
SELECT * from Entity
WHERE
    attribute1 = ?
AND attribute2 > ?
AND attribute3 IN (????)
AND (
        (attribute4 = ? AND attribute5 IN (???))
    OR  (attribute4 = ? AND attribute5 IN (???))
    OR  (attribute4 = ? AND attribute5 IN (???))
)
;
```

[AbstractWhereDSL](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/apidocs/org/mybatis/dynamic/sql/where/AbstractWhereDSL.html) accepts only `BindableColumn` and `ExistsPredicate`.

If I do something like

```
ret = ret.applyWhere(where -> where
    .and(attribute4,isEqualTo(x)).and(attribute5,isIn(y))
    .or(attribute4,isEqualTo(z)).and(attribute5,isIn(a))
);
```

I will end up into a flat query

```
SELECT * from Entity
WHERE
    attribute1 = ?
AND attribute2 > ?
AND attribute3 IN (????)

AND attribute4 = ?
AND attribute5 IN (???)
OR  attribute4 = ?
AND attribute5 IN (???)
OR  attribute4 = ?
AND attribute5 IN (???)
;
```

Which is bad in my scenario.

**Question**: how can I create a sub-predicate in a where condition in Mybtis Dynamic SQL?

**Context**: while I have discussed this multiple times with the team, I need to segregate queries according to attribute-based visibility. The attributes are two and must be in combination. I have already optimized the query to group all values of `attribute5` (legal entity ID) that come along with the same `attribute4` (workflow type) in the permission set, otherwise the final query becomes an endless list of `(attribute4 = ? and attribute5 = ?)`

In this context, it would be extremely simple to do `attribute4 in (?) and attribute5 in (?)` but some results would be acceptable (you can see legal entity ACME in workflow PERFORMANCE, but not in COMPLIANCE, to provide an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `mybatis-dynamic-sql` library version `1.4.0`, It supports grouping of where conditions. Please refer below git link for reference

https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/complexquery/GroupingTest.java